# Web based chat between users in my web app

Tags: php, angularjs, chat

I would like my users to able to chat with one another.

I currently use angularjs as the front-end and PHP in the back-end.

any ideas?

Comment: *"any ideas?"* - Any code?

Comment: ...I guess not.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, or at least post what you have tried so far (code)/what you're trying to do (more specifically). This way, it's more likely users on SO can help you.

Comment: Please do not treat StackOverflow as a discussion forum. Here, only clear and concise question that can be answered objectively should be posted here. "_Any ideas?_" is not a clear question at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at different languages for this. Node.js, MongoDB and Redis is a good start.

Also, just expecting people to give you code with such a vague request is not really in line with the spirit of things here.  There are plenty of good examples online and a simple Google search would give you results like this https://github.com/joni2back/spachat if you're really keen on using PHP and Angular.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't looking for code, but a general direction. The problem with Node.js is the hosting. I currently us shared hosting which doesn't support Node.js. Do you think I can implement it in Heroku or Firebase? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at evennode.com

Comment: Heroku will do just fine too. Nothing is stopping you from using PHP and Angular. It will work but it won't scale well when you start having high amounts of connections.  I've built a chat solution in PHP using Ajax and MySQL but it really does get quite heavy after a while...

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot